# Custom Dropdowns in Data Validation

Tags: excel

I cannot find if this is possible.

I have an Employees table with the following columns - Payroll Number, First Name, Surname

On another sheet users then fill in the employee details along with other data such as hours worked and pay rate etc

Users do not want to have to enter the Name twice. Is it possible to add a dropdown to the payroll number column on the 2nd sheet which would allow the user to select a Payroll Number but when using the dropdown it should be displayed as 000000 - Bloggs, Joe

[image: Example]

Dropdown to look as per the image, but only display the payroll number once selected: [image: Dropdown Image]

Comment: You need to create a helper column in employee table. Then concatenate payroll, surname & First Name to that column. Finally use data validation to show list from thaat helper column.

Comment: When selected I only want the payroll number to be in the cell